# Create fixed width output using Hadlebarjs

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

Im trying to use `Handlebarsjs` to create fixed width text output. I need to have fixed width that is set; ie 60 characters and operate within that boundary. If the variable width extends over that limit I need to put it on the next line. Indicate that it continues there. If the variable is less than boundary I need to fill the remaining space with white space characters and close the section with its closing tag.

template example:

```
  /* ---------------------------------------------------- */
  /* Row1: {{var1}}                                       */
  /* Row2: {{var2}}                                       */
  /* ---------------------------------------------------- */
```

should output:

```
  /* ---------------------------------------------------- */
  /* Row 1: Fits within row limit                         */
  /* Row 2: Doe not fit within row limit because it is too+
  long                                                    */
  /* ---------------------------------------------------- */
```

What are the best options to do this using `Handlebarsjs`?